# NSDictionary seems to have multiple values for one key, how do I access the individual values?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am using ADAL to authenticate to Azure AD, it returns an dictionary with claims, one of the keys is the groups that a user is a member of,

The full dictionary looks like this

```
2017-06-05 17:40:58.712 NWMobileTill[46676:3282242] userInfoStore Item all {
    alg = none;
    amr =     (
        pwd
    );
    aud = "042a00fc-b832-411f-xxxxxxxx";
    exp = xxxxxxx;
    groups =     (
        "xxx-9725-43f6-a502-xxxxx",
        "38c5b3af-xxx-4b38-b180-xxxx"
    );
    iat = xxx;
    ipaddr = "xx";
    iss = "https://xxxxxxx/xxx-d61d-xxx-a949-0cb72eff23be/";
    name = "POS Test";
    nbf = xxx;
    oid = "c44f91f2-xx-40bb-9624-xxx";
    platf = 2;
    sub = "xxxxx";
    tid = "b5154a9e-xxx-4d55-a949-xxx";
    typ = JWT;
    "unique_name" = "nwpos@xxxxxx";
    upn = "nwpos@xxxx";
    ver = "1.0";
}
```

when I access they values in the NSDIctionary using the objectForKey as below

```
NSDictionary *jongel = [result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.allClaims objectForKey:@"groups"];
```

I get multiple entries like this,

```
2017-06-05 17:40:58.712 NWMobileTill[46676:3282242] Groups are (
"xx-9725-43f6-a502-xx",
"xx-d0dc-4b38-xx-17555db6f626"
)
```

I am confused that I can get multiple values, how do I access each individual value? I happen to assign this to an NSDictionary but I don't know if that is right. How can I get to those individual entries?

Comment: Seems to be a NSArray to me.

Comment: you mean the groups is an NSArray inside an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups is an array, so when you do the `[objectForKey...]` call it returns the data as expected. I would assign the returned object to an `NSArray` as it should always be returned as from that data model as an array, even if it only contains one element.
If you're more curious you can add a breakpoint in and examine it in a debugger, the `[objectForKey...`] method does some interesting behaviour around type conversions and sometimes the results may surprise you.